# Autoconnect a database with sqltalk from cmd

Tags: database, cmd, sqltalk

I want to autoconnect a database using sqltalk from cmd. Is there any way to do that?

Comment: What command line have you tried? What does the sqltalk documentation say about this?

Comment: If you need to know more about SQLBase /  SQLTalk, here is a link to some manuals for every version from v8 thru v12.1  :  http://samples.tdcommunity.net/index.php?dir=SqlBase/SqlBase_Books/